# What should I do when my company threatens to give a bad review to my university if I quit my job?

Tags: internship

I'm in an internship, and I want to quit my job because it is entirely different from the job description. However, my company threatens to give a bad review to the university, ask for a penalty and will harm my career prospects. What should I do?

Comment: You should report this to the university yourself. Evidence would be helpful. Do you have this in writing?

Comment: Have you thought about checking [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) as they may also have very good insights, experience, and maybe answers? Nonetheless, choice about what to do should be yours...

Comment: @Roland He threatened me verbally. Moreover, I really want to get the replacement job as it is a very promising job and aligned to my career goals. But I'm scared that if I quit, I will fail this internship program from the university and cannot graduate on time.

Comment: @OldPadawan Thank you for your comment, I will try to ask on that platform.

Comment: Also, May I now why people downvote my question? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Report it to the university.

Comment: @James : be careful not cross-posting though

Comment: @Roland thank you, I will try to talk with my university. Wish me luck :)

Comment: One thing: You say "my company threaten me" and later "he threatened my". Is "he" and "the company" the same? If "he" is your manager, your company might be shocked at your manager's behaviour. So find out what "the company" really thinks about it. Unless "he" is the company owner. I worked at one _huge_ company where "he" would be in serious trouble.

Comment: @gnasher729 I work in a startup and the "he" that I mentioned is the CEO of the company.

Comment: I can promise you that the startup won't last.

Comment: @gnasher729 I thought so. The management is very bad, there are no proper project management and no certain timeline. I really want to quit this job but worry that he spread bad rumors about me to other companies. Will he have such capability to do so?

Comment: I think you got downvoted (but not by me) because your post is lacking a lot of relevant detail: is this an internship or a side  job? Was that arranged by the university or my yourself. Are you getting paid or not? Is this is a limited time contract 
 or full time. What's the country? What are the formal requirements from the university? Do you have an internship department at your university that manages this type of thing ?

Comment: My last boss for example was quite good at figuring out people. If your current boss told him fibs about you, he would figure it out easily, and it would backfire on your boss. Actually, even if you were as bad as your boss says, spreading this is something that is just not done. Not in the UK where I live. So if my boss believed the stories, then he would still send your boss packing because of bad behaviour, and maybe be a bit more careful in an interview. Maybe you didn't work in an obviously bad environment. We had a good environment so we'd expect you to work out better.

Comment: Please indicate country. The work environment can be wildly different in a India than in the US, for example -- enough so that I tend to skip questions tagged as India because my answers are unlikely to be useful.

Comment: Note that in your actual career, almost any job contract carries the phrase "and other duties as assigned" or some equivalent. You _will_ occasionally find yourself doing things outside your formal job description. When that happens, talk to your manager about how long they will need you in that role and about whether it is good or bad for your career. Not knowing the details of your situation, I can't say whether that would be more appropriate here than just quitting.

Answer (score 74):

You don't want to work in a place that is not appropiate for your career regardless of the threats of bad reviews.

I also have a gut feeling that these are void promises. Companies risk losing their collaboration agreement (hence cheap workforce) with the university if their interns have bad experiences there. It seems the company made a mess getting you there and they don't want you to quit so they don't lose the bargain, hence they think you will stay by threatening you.

Report this situation to your university exactly as you are doing here. All the wrongdoing is by that company. State the facts, job is different from the description, company threatened you in giving a bad review if you quit.

They might still give a negative review, but if you have also sent a complaint about the company to the university, they will at most disregard both complaints (no one wants to be part in a labor conflict) or start an audit process to clarify what happened.

The greatest party in loss here is the company, not you. And you have no other choice, staying is going to be harmful for your career and your wellbeing.

Comment: In a lot of universities, each department has an academic responsible for internships and similar placements. They'll be a good contact

Comment: @ChrisH Depends on jurisdiction. In Canada (particularly BC), co-op programs are handled by separate departments (yes, plural: each faculty has its own co-op program). Problems like this would be handled by the student's co-op program.

Comment: @zmike a slightly different structure, just at faculty rather than school level. I'm not surprised.

Comment: _"I don't think they will give a bad review about you"_ when I had an intern from university in our team, we were expected by the university to evaluate them (i.e. send regular evaluation reports to the university). If that intern would have left or quit early that would definitely have resulted in a negative evaluation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I agree on that, they can send in a negative report, but when you are also giving negative comments about the company to the university with objective proof, these reports will not factor in as negatively as if you really had misbehaved or underperformed

Comment: "Companies risk losing their collaboration agreement" is a very specific assumption that depends entirely on local culture. As an example, the way internships work where I live is that the student, who is required to do an industry internship as a part of their major, applies to a company on their own and in the end, they deliver a report to the university. There usually is no agreement or direct contact between the university and the company at all. In general, with enough negative experiences with that place, most students will learn in term before applying there, so your point still holds.

Comment: I don't think there's enough details in the question for this answer. It's possible this is correct, or it's also possible the OP had unrealistic expectations and will look really bad for quitting, or anywhere in between.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My understanding was that the company didn’t threaten “if you leave we will report that you left”, but “if you leave then we will make up all kinds of nonsense about you”.

Comment: @gnasher729 We have only the unclear description of the OP to go on. Their description of the "threat" could also be a misinterpretation on their part of the manager explaining consequences. For example, _"if you end the internship early, we will give a negative evaluation, which might result in a failing grade and that could harm your career prospects."_ could easily be misinterpreted or misrepresented to the description of the threat in the question.

Answer (score 25):

**Talk to your university.**

Assuming you got this internship through your university as part of your studies then your university will be extremely interested to know that the company gave an incorrect job description. Usually that will draw a visit from the university placement coordinator and the possibility that the company will be excluded from future internships. Of course they will want to know details of what you were promised and what you are doing before they take such a step.

You can and should also check with your university what the impact on your studies will be if you change internship. Always do this before changing internships for any reason.

Also your university will tell you the effect of your company giving you a "bad review" (I don't expect it to be much effect under the circumstances).

Answer (score 9):

I think it is entirely normal that a manager will *warn* you that they will give negative feedback on your internship to your university/school if you decide to up and quit in the middle of your internship.

In my experience, a university or school requests (and requires) feedback and evaluation of you from the company where you intern, which sometimes even results in a passing/failing grade of your internship. You leaving before the end of your internship is something that will and should result in a negative evaluation, because you basically will have failed your internship.

In other words, I think your manager didn't threaten you, they established the consequences of you ending your internship early, so you can make an informed decision.

Your concerns about the internship not matching the description may be valid, but just quitting is not the right reaction for an intern, as it might result in a failing grade. I recommend that you discuss this with a mentor or whoever supervises your internship at the university or school *before* you end your internship, to see what the effects are of doing this, and whether or not it is a good idea to do so, what alternatives you have, or if it is better to just hold on until the end of the internship. And possibly the university/school can address the mismatch between the description and actual work in a better way than you can.

Comment: It's hard to know whether it was a threat or statement of fact, and the OP is not providing much information. It could be either: there are unscrupulous bosses who'll attempt to blackmail interns, but equally, a warning could be given without any malice. Definitely better to go through official channels, at least initially, unless the employer is behaving in a totally egregious and clearly illegal way.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'd do:

I'd focus on getting the replacement job you referenced in your comment, hand in your notice to your current Internship provider and walk away.

You may need to talk with your University if part of your course requirements are tied to your current job - but from your description of what was said to you - it sounds like Piss, Vineagar and Wind (AKA Bluster and BS - they don't want you to go, so are threatening) - hence why I'd just focus on the next opportunity and then resign.

Answer (score 1):

In [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales), this could amount to blackmail, which is a criminal offence. The definition of blackmail is found at [Section 21 of the Theft Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/section/21):

> A person is guilty of blackmail if, with a view to gain for himself or
> another or with intent to cause loss to another, he makes any
> unwarranted demand with menaces; and for this purpose a demand with
> menaces is unwarranted unless the person making it does so in the
> belief—
>
> (a) that he has reasonable grounds for making the demand; and
>
> (b) that the use of the menaces is a proper means of reinforcing the
> demand.

In this case, the demand is that you involuntarily keep working for the company, and the menaces are that they will try to sabotage your reputation and career if you do not agree.

One factor in whether or not there are reasonable grounds / proper means is whether or not you have a contractual obligation to continue working (e.g. you are attempting to leave in 1 week when the contract requires a 1 month notice period). You didn't specify that level of detail so I'm assuming you do have the contractual right to leave on your proposed last day.

Comment: Given the lack of detail in the question, it is hard to say if this is blackmail, or just a case of a manager (badly?) trying to explain the consequences of rash actions like terminating your intership to a clueless student.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That could well be the case. For example, if OP says "I'm quitting" and the company responds "Fine. We're going give a bad review to the university" then that isn't blackmail because there is no demand; it is simply stating a fact. However, if the response is "If you do then we're going to give a bad review" you're now potentially implying a demand with menaces. For my answer I took the question at face value where it stated "my company threatens to give a bad review", which tends to suggest the latter (since a threat tends to be conditional on a demand being met).